# How to model a for loop in a neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I am currently in the process of learning neural networks and can understand basic examples like AND, OR, Addition, Multiplication, etc.

Right now, I am trying to build a neural network that takes two inputs x and n, and computes pow(x, n). And, this would require the neural network to have some form of a loop, and I am not sure how I can model a network with a loop

Can this sort of computation be modelled on a neural network? I am assuming it is possible.. based on the recently released paper(Neural Turing Machine), but not sure how. Any pointers on this would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe with a recurrent neural net.

Comment: Hey Oli, thanks.. I actually found this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation_through_time - you can see the image on the page describing how the flow looks like. I think we would need something like that. I am exploring a bit more on that. Thanks for the pointer! :)

Answer (score 4):

Feedforward neural nets are not Turing-complete, and in particular they cannot model loops of arbitrary order. However, if you fix the maximum `n` that you want to treat, then you can set up an architecture which can model loops with up to `n` repetitions. For instance, you could easily imagine that each layer could act as one iteration in the loop, so you might need `n` layers.

For a more general architecture that can be made Turing-complete, you could use [Recurrent Neural Networks (RNN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network). One popular instance in this class are the so-called [Long short-term memory (LSTM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short_term_memory) networks by Hochreiter and Schmidhuber. Training such RNNs is quite different from training classical feedforward networks, though.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll look into Recurrent Neural Networks and Long Short Term Memory. Thanks for the explanation and pointers! :)

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed out, [Neural Turing Machines](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.5401) seem to working well to learn the basic algorithms. For instance, the repeat copy task which has been implemented in the paper, might tell us that NTM can learn the algorithm itself. As of now, NTMs have been used only for simple tasks so understanding its scope by using the pow(x,n) will be interesting given that repeat copy works well. I suggest reading [Reinforcement Learning Neural Turing Machines - Revised](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.00521v3.pdf) for a deeper understanding.

Also, recent developments in the area of `Memory Networks` empower us to perform more complicated tasks. Hence,  to make a neural network understand pow(x,n) might be possible. So go ahead and give it a shot!